# Applying boosts inside a SpanQuery

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there a way to apply a boost inside a SpanOrQuery? (Solr 7.1, lucene of same version.)

Example of query structure generated by edismax query parser (inside the usual +BooleanQuery / DisjunctionMaxQuery for multiple fields):

- SpanNearQuery

  - List of SpanOrQuery

    - List of SpanTermQuery or SpanNearQuery <-- I want to boost those terms

I want to apply a boost to each clause inside the SpanOrQuery. So I tried (via custom query parser extending edismax):

- SpanNearQuery

  - List of SpanOrQuery

    - List of SpanBoostQuery, each wrapping:

      - a SpanTermQuery or a SpanNearQuery.

The boost seems to be ignored, although the query is executed successfully (except boost not applied).

Here is the use case:

> The input is a sentence, a phrase query (quoted with slop) to valuate proximity. I am using edismax query parser and a SynonymGraphFilter and I want to apply a different boost for each synonym, so the boost information is attached to each term in the synonym file (e.g. 0.7_foo). In case of multi-term synonyms (expanded version), edismax generates a SpanQuery, which sounds to me like a graph search, so far so good.
>
> Where it fails is when I insert a SpanBoostQuery to wrap each clause inside the SpanOrQuery (via a custom query parser extending edismax, extracting boosts from term text). While the query is still returning results, the boost seems just ignored.

Is that a misusage? A bug? Any advice about how I can fix it or work around it please?

To have a similar behavior, I replaced the SpanQuery by a list of PhraseQueries, one for each possible combination of terms in the SpanQuery, which can result in lots of phrases, the performances seem highly affected and we lose lots of information.

Thanks a lot!

***Edit:***

The tree above describes the query generated by my custom query parser (I checked the resulting Query by debugging it), but for whoever wants to figure out how this is implemented, I first let edismax return a parsed query, then I go through the tree recursively, rebuilding a new Query, until I reach the leaf (SpanTermQuery), and I apply a code like below to wrap the term in a boost (SpanBoostQuery is provided by lucene).

```
if (initialQuery instanceof SpanTermQuery) {
    SpanTermQuery q = (SpanTermQuery) initialQuery;
    // parse and extract term/boost from q.getTerm(),
    // e.g. "0.7_foo" -> {term: foo, boost: 0.7}
    q = new SpanTermQuery(term);
    if (boost >= 0 && boost != 1) {
        return new SpanBoostQuery(q, boost);
    } else {
        return q;
    }
}
```

I am aware it is not an optimal solution, but so far it works except the missing boost. Advices are welcome, but it would be a separate topic, and not as important for me as my question above :)

Comment: Ok, your use case is clear.
It may potentially be a misusage : the first thing I would have thought are payloads for your use case[1] .

Anyway I am curious to understand what it is not working, can you share your implementation for the SpanBoostQuery ?


[1] https://lucidworks.com/2017/09/14/solr-payloads/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm afraid the payload implementation doesn't suit well to my use case since it's for indexing-time synonym expansion, and I need to support multi-terms, thus use query-time synonym expansion. I added in my question a piece of code and explanation about the current implementation. Any idea about what could be wrong to apply the boost is welcome :) It seems that, in the past, there used to be a method to "set" a boost in an existing Query term, that seem to have been replaced by those *BoostQuery.

Comment: Ok, your code seems fairly ok, and I was checking the implementation of the Lucene SpanBoostQuery which is quite basic as well.
You mentioned you debugged, so when you say that is not boosting, is it the createWeight method which doesn't work all right ?
Or what is the point you lose the boost ?

Comment: I didn't debug at this level of detail, I have checked the output Query and the tree seemed OK (a SpanNearQuery containing SpanBoostQuery's, containging a SpanTermQuery...). But the boost has no impact on the final order of results, regardless of the boost I apply (very big number, very small number...). When using other types of queries (Phrases, tokens), I could notice that changing the boost changed the final order. If you have any idea about where I could start debugging, it would be welcome. Just keep in mind I'm quite new to Solr and lucene :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: What i would do, is put a breakpoint at the create weight method and run a query.
At that point you should see the boost applied and in case it is not you can start your investigations.
For example the boost can be missing at that level ? maybe it becomes 0 because of type conversions ? ect ect

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find out more in the coming days.